# Are all ODE's that have a constant solution separable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why I thought this was first it can be shown that all linear ODE's have this property.
Like if you think of the general form of a linear ODE, $y'+y*f(x)=g(x)$; substitute $y=k$,
$f(x)*k=g(x)$, which implies $k=g(x)/f(x)$, you don't need to worry about $f(x)=0$, as that leads to $0=g(x)$, which goes against the assumption $y=k$. Substituting $f(x)*k=g(x)$, We get $y'=f(x)(k-y)$ which is separable. So, it is shown that all linear ODE that have a constant solution can be written as a separable ODE. My question is does this generalize to all ODE's? Intuitively, I thought well you must need $y'=f(k)=0$, for this to be true, so if you have like $y'=f(y)+g(x)$, that won't work (non-separable), but $y'=f(y)*g(x)$, does work and is separable.
I am just taking a normal ODE class, but just thought of this. Can anyone give advice on this reasoning? Thank you.

Comment: $y'+xy^2=y^3$ has $y=0$ as a solution but is not separable at first glance.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Would it work if you imposed that there must be a constant power of y in the equation? Was my reasoning at least right about linear ODE's?